# Scalaz and main method

Tags: scala, haskell, monads, scalaz

I'm trying to learn Scalaz with a toy project of mine, I used monads in Haskell and now I want to learn how to use them in Scala with Scalaz.

The big question is, how does one use the `IO()` Monad in the Scala's main method?

In Haskell, the main function is of type `IO()` and in Scala it is of type `()`.

The solution I found so far was to create another function `foo` of type `IO()` and in the main method call `foo.unsafePerformIO()`. But this makes me cringe.

What could be a solution?

Comment: There's no point and the exercise would be futile - Scala is an **impure** functional language. Scala is not Haskell and Haskell is not Scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scala's native main method is meant to be side effectful; calling `unsafePerformIO` in it is completely safe.

In fact, considering most Scala projects aren't 100% pure/Scalaz code, this approach is probably the most idiomatic one. Someone might have provided an "elegance" wrapper for it, but it wouldn't add any value besides cosmetics. And, again, most of the time you'd be embedding a Scalaz IO action inside a more mainstream, non-pure and possibly even non-functional Scala code anyway.

Furthermore, in general, and even in Haskell, the `unsafe` functions are typically just `makeSureYouKnowWhatYoureDoing` functions.

Comment: In Haskell, there's a continuum of unsafety, ranging from `unsafeInterleaveIO` on the safe side all the way up to `unsafeDupablePerformIO` on the eat-your-shorts side.

Comment: And all of these can be used if you know what you're doing, right?

Comment: No doubt. Some lead to more bugs than others, but all have their uses.

Comment: I agree with everything said here, but there is such a wrapper in Scalaz, and using it is at least arguably more Scalaz-idiomatic (for whatever that's worth), so this isn't really an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: (For the record I wouldn't downvote this—I think it's reasonable information.)

Answer (score 7):

Scalaz provides a [`SafeApp` trait](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/effect/src/main/scala/scalaz/effect/SafeApp.scala) that allows you to replace Scala's side-effectful `main` method with a wrapper that looks more like Haskell's `main`:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._, effect.{ IO, SafeApp }

object MyMain extends SafeApp {
  override def runl(args: List[String]): IO[Unit] = IO(println("hello world"))
}
```

Now `MyMain` can be used like any other JVM class with a static `main`.

I don't personally use `SafeApp` much, but it's there if you want to avoid calling `unsafePerformIO` by hand.

Comment: Since you don't use it much, Travis, do you simply do: `def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = ioReturningMethod.unsafePerformIO`?

Comment: I am using the latest ScalaZ version `7.2.27` but when I am calling `scalaz.effect.SafeApp` I get `object effect is not a member of package scalaz` any idea why ?

Comment: @Wonay Do you have scalaz-effect as a dependency?